# A store I visited is breaching PCI DSS. What should I do?

Tags: pci-dss

I recently visited a store in Northern Ireland and paid using my Visa debit card. The receipt shows my entire card number and expiry date. It also contains other info. I thought this should all be crossed out as now they have a copy of my card number and details which was not encrypted or hidden.

Comment: Contact your bank. Let them know the merchant, when, and where.

Comment: A former employer of mine did far worse than this with customer data. Ratting them out went nowhere; merchants that process less than 10,000 transactions per month don't seem to be worth auditors' time.

Comment: @Ivan Small merchants usually get away using PCI DSS self-assesment questionaries and third party security assessments of such entities are usually performed only in case of confirmed account security program violation. But I'd like to indicate that in this particular case, they clearly violate payment brand rules and not necessary PCI DSS. PCI does not prohibit printing PAN on receipt. Requirement 3.3 does not work here, because customer simply walks away with the receipt and we don't know if the merchant stores the copy AND violates reqs 9.5, 9.6, 9.7 and 9.8.1 at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

Printing full PAN and expiry date on the customer receipt is a violation of Visa's requirements listed in "Card Acceptance Guidelines for Visa Merchants". Therefore I suggest you to submit merchant violation complaint form directly to Visa. It is located here: https://usa.visa.com/Forms/merchant-violation-complaint-form.html

Comment: Is it still a violation if it's an Irish company operating overseas? Or does that guideline only apply to Visa USA?

Comment: @Hollowproc Yes. Requirements for account information suppression come from Visa International Operating Regulations. There are no current exceptions for specific regions.

Answer (score 4):

Start by contacting your bank / debit card company and have your account number changed and your card reissued. I don't know there's much to do beyond that. If you let the bank know what merchant this happened at in IR, they may follow-up, but I don't know what IR requires from a CC standpoint, or if they even care about being PCI compliant; outside of the US, it can be a bit less of the "standard". YMMV.

Answer (score -3):

First, report the *private data stealing/improper handling* to police and **make sure to obtain a paper from them where the case/complain number and date is stated**. It's a very important moment! And - **keep the receipt to yourself**! Attach a copy to your police invoice. After that contact your bank, supplying the incident details, a scan of a receipt and the number from police. Obtain a call audio recording - and your bank support ticket ID. Next step is to contact their payment processor/bank - you can read the name in your receipt, obtain a ticket number too, audio record the support conversation too. After that give the receipt numbers to the police and ask them to attach it to your case, and tell your bank the processor's ticket ID.

I had similar problem in Russia, so I know what I'm talking about just basing on my own experience. This action sequence will **not** allow to leave your case unresolved, and - especially if your card data will be used to steal your money - it will save you from losses.

Comment: You make it sound as though a criminal offence is committed by printing full card details on the receipt. The law in the UK is not necessarily the same as Russia (and the law in NI is not necessarily the same as in Great Britain). If the card receipt is one of the manual card-impression type, it will always have all this information. There isn't any proof in the question here that the store has actually kept any data which it shouldn't or in any form it shouldn't.

Comment: @AndrewLeach it did - all the POS machines must have a "black box recorder" for **all** thr receipts it has issued. It's a regulatory and fail-safe requirement to such kind of equipment. It can be printed on a second paper roll inside it or stored electronically - but there's **always** two **identical** copies of all the receipts printed : one pops out, another one is kept inside a box

Comment: In which case it's exactly the same as a manual impression, except that it hasn't recorded the signature or PIN. Manual impression machines are still used. There's still no evidence that the store has anything it shouldn't. Nor is it a police matter in the UK until any data is actually misused.

Comment: @AndrewLeach as far as I know, your card data is your personal data

Comment: As far as I know, credit card handling violation is normally handled as a civil issue, not a criminal issue. Police generally don't have authority over civil issues, so they usually won't get involved unless there's clear indication of a criminal element.

Comment: @LieRyan as far as I know police - if decides that it's not their type of case - routes it to the appropriate governmental organ/organization that deals specifically with that type of cases.

Comment: All the "as far as I know"s are a problem. There is no Data Protection case in this instance in the UK. While card data is personal data, it's highly likely that processing and holding that data is absolutely fine. On the facts stated, there is only an issue if a fraud is committed using that data, or it falls into the wrong hands. Holding the data does violate Visa's rules, but it's not a matter for the police or the Information Commissioner's Office.

Comment: @AndrewLeach in Russia it's a law that if you've put your invoice in a wrong agency they must reroute it